# Responsive JQuery / Javascript issues on Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, resize, media-queries

I am working on a responsive "mega menu" using @Media querys in CSS. Instead of using the width attribute because of inconsistency with CSS, I am basing the below if statement on a CSS rule, as I know this rule will change with my media query. Some of the below code will be unnecessary for this question, but I wanted to include it all.

Basically if i load the page on the mobile view (where the if statement returns true) I am toggling my divs to show with a click, but after toggling / untoggling, If i then resize my page to the larger size (css then changes to float left, if no longer returns true), the menu item i toggled on and off will no longer show that div on hover, which it would if i had loaded the page initially in the larger size. This function should be running on resize so I can't seem to see why this would be the case?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {                

    checkSize();
    $(window).resize(checkSize);                

});

function checkSize() {
    if ($(".nav > li").css("float") != "left" ) {
        $(".nav > li > a").bind("click", function(){
            $(this).parent().children("div").toggle();
        });
    } else {
        $("#storeContent > div").hide();
        $("#storeContent > div:first").show();

        $("#storeLinks > ul > li > a").bind("mouseover", function(){
            $("#storeLinks > ul > li > a").css({backgroundColor: "#ffffff", color: "#7b7b7b"});               
            $("#storeContent > div").hide();
            $("#storeContent > div" + $(this).attr('href')).show();
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: "#3c759e", color: "#ffffff"});   

            $("#dropdown").height($("#storeContent").height());
            $("#storeLinks").height($("#dropdown").height());
        });

        $("#storeLinks > ul > li > a").bind("click", function(){
            return false;
        });

        $(".nav > li > a").bind("mouseover", function(){
            $("#storeContent > div").hide();
            $("#storeLinks").height($("#dropdown").height());
            $("#storeContent > div:first").show();
            $("#storeLinks > ul > li > a").css({backgroundColor: "#ffffff", color: "#7b7b7b"}); 
        });

        $("#storeLinks > ul > li > a").bind("mouseover", function(){
            $(".storeColumn + div > img").hide();
            $(".storeColumn + div > img:first-child").show();
        });     

        $(".storeColumn > .subNav > li").bind("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).closest("div").siblings("div").children("img").hide();
            $(this).closest("div").siblings("div").children("img" + $(this.firstChild).attr('href')).show();
        });
    }
}
```

The CSS which effects the same DIVs as in the if statement block is as follows (part of the media query for when the page is in full desktop size). These divs are initially set to display:none.

```
.nav > li:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `checkSize` is running at all on resize first by using `console.log` for example?

Comment: Hi there, I have tested this is running on resize by running an alert on the else statement and then resizing to the larger size, which successfully calls the alert. I have also done this in reverse, using an alert in the if block and resizing down from the larger size, so it appears to be running fine.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to do but you do know that `checkSize` will run on every resize and not just once, right?

Comment: I know this is the case, which is intended. The problem im having is that after toggling the divs on / off, when i resize to the larger size, the CSS behavior that would have shown the divs on hover (added to post as edit) no longer works for the div i toggled.

Comment: Honestly, I would try first to refactor the code into different functions doing one task each. Your function does kind of everything at once so it is tricky to see what you're trying to achieve. Also, we haven't seen your html structure.